# Implementing complex AI in an ECS?

Tags: game-design, architecture, ai, mmo, entity-component-system

I'm having a hard time wrapping around how something quite stateful such as complex AI would be handled in a pure ECS (such as components being only data and systems operating on that data)

Things like different enemies in a game that cast different spells, or bosses with various phases and abilities like in an MMO.Usually i'd handle such a thing with data and behaviour components and state machines, but this violates the data-driven ECS paradigm.

Is there an easy way to handle this sort of behaviour in an ECS or is a different approach required?

Comment: Do these past Q&A threads on the issue help? [ECS: AI components and systems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116376/39518) / [What is the component for the AI system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/75222/39518) / [AI and EntitySystem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134754/39518) / [How can I build GOAP within an ECS?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/152123/39518) / [How to implement behaviour in a component-based architecture?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8932/39518) / [Should components in ECS have logic?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/167058/39518)

Comment: Thank you, in some ways there were helpful. I got stuck in the notion that everything had to be done through ecs if it was implemented which is not true. I suppose for Ai that is generally quite stateful those components themselves could behave as data / behaviour components exclusively and leave the other components as pure data / systems. 

Comment: Got the answers you need? Should we close this question as a duplicate of one of those links? Or would you like to edit your question to refine it based on what you've gleaned, and focus on an issue the existing links don't cover?